How to properly add multiple canvas into a PDF?
I wrote a Java program with iText 9.0.0 to create a PDF file. I need to add external PDFs as XObjects to every page of a PDF. Everything goes fine if the number of the PDF pages is 1 or 2. However, if the number of pages >= 3 (for example change int n = 30;  to int n = 31; in the following code), the program crashes and the PDF will be unable to generate correctly. This behavior is really eerie!
package net.opho;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.PdfCanvas;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.xobject.PdfXObject;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PdfDocument output = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("C:\\develop\\demo.pdf"));
        Document document = new Document(output);
        document.setTopMargin(120);
        Paragraph paragraph = (new Paragraph("Some texts...")).setFontSize(24);
        int n = 30;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            document.add(paragraph);
        }
        PdfDocument logoPdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("C:\\develop\\OPhOLogo.pdf"));
        PdfXObject logoObject = logoPdf.getFirstPage().copyAsFormXObject(output);
        logoPdf.close();
        Rectangle logoRectangle = PdfXObject.calculateProportionallyFitRectangleWithWidth(logoObject, 20, 750, 200);
        for (int i = 1; i <= output.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(output, i);
            canvas.addXObjectFittedIntoRectangle(logoObject, logoRectangle);
        }
        output.close();
    }
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Map.get(Object)" because "this.map" is null
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDictionary.get(PdfDictionary.java:471)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDictionary.getAsNumber(PdfDictionary.java:184)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage.getRotation(PdfPage.java:151)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.PdfCanvas.<init>(PdfCanvas.java:229)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.PdfCanvas.<init>(PdfCanvas.java:271)
    at net.opho.Main.main(Main.java:25)



The PdfReader should be closed after use.

Especially thanks for K J's help and advice. The function public static Rectangle calculateProportionallyFitRectangleWithWidth(PdfXObject xObject, float x, float y, float width) is correct, where x and y are coordinates of the lower-left corner of the rectangle respectively, width is the width of the rectangle, the height of the rectangle will be automatically calculated to be proportional to the width, which keeps the invariance of the XObject's width-height ratio.

More information can be found in iText documentation.

I have tried your revised version of that PDF logo. Unfortunately, the problem still exists. I have tried other PDFs, and I encounter the same problem. So, it's likely not the problem of PDF files, but some mistakes of my Java code or iText's behavior. If there is a problem in PDF file, it can't explain why everything goes fine when the number of pages is less than 3.

I don't think the reason is about memory (or other resources) will be exhausted when there are more than 2 pages. But your opinion, to stamp the logo, is really a good idea. I will further investigate iText documentation and research whether there are some approaches with stamping features that can achieve "inject reference once use many", which is helpful to reduce memory consumption as well as output file size. But I still think my code above should be fixed in some way and work fine.

iText flushes created pages as soon as possible to the output steam and clears them from memory to conserve resources. Thus, you have to either disable this mechanism, or add your graphics early (using page events), or add them in a second pass.

To disable this early flushing mechanism use the three-parameter Document constructor and set the boolean immediateFlush parameter to false. Also see this answer.

@mkl 's suggestion is helpful! After changing the above code to Document document = new Document(output, PageSize.A4, false); , everything goes correctly. By the way, after this code change I should also change output.close(); to document.close(); , otherwise the texts will not be rendered.

Yes, when using a Document, you need to close it, and closing it implicitly closes the PdfDocument. Usually the easiest way is to use try-with-resources.

To turn the solution found in the comments into an answer:
iText by default flushes created pages as soon as possible to the output steam and clears them from memory to conserve resources. Thus, you have to either disable this mechanism, or add your graphics early (using page events), or add them in a second pass.
To disable this early flushing mechanism use the three-parameter Document constructor and set the boolean immediateFlush parameter to false. Also see this answer.

after this code change I should also change output.close(); to document.close();, otherwise the texts will not be rendered.

Yes, when using a Document, you need to close it, and closing it implicitly closes the PdfDocument. Usually the easiest way is to use try-with-resources.
